# custom grouping of pd.df, calculate OHLC in vectorised fashion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, python-3.8

I would like to get Open/High/Low/Close for chunks of a dataframe where `df.volume >= threshold`.
Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2018-01-02', periods=10000, freq='ms'),
                  data=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10000, 2)),
                  columns=['price', 'volume'])
df.head()
                       price volume
2018-01-02 00:00:00.000   19    4
2018-01-02 00:00:00.001   49    9
2018-01-02 00:00:00.002    2    5
2018-01-02 00:00:00.003   12   82
2018-01-02 00:00:00.004   42   32
```

I can achieve the desired result by iterating over `iterrows()` which is painfully slow:

```
threshold = 5000
vol = 0
count = 1
group = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    vol += row['volume']
    if vol >= threshold:
        count +=1
        vol = 0
    group.append(count)
df['group'] = group

df.groupby('group').agg({'price': 'ohlc'})
```

I have 70 Dataframes with ~3mio rows each to process and the for loop takes ~2:30mins.
Hence I would appreciate a vectorised approach. Is there a way to replace the for loop with a vectorised solution?

Comment: Can you add an example of what your expected output is? It's not very clear to me. Find sequential parts in the dataframe with df.volume > 5000 and get some price statistics from those?

Comment: made it a little clearer. so find sequential chunks where cumsum >= 5000. then I need to find the start, max, min, and end price ('OHLC' in resample provides that)

Comment: So in the above example, if the condition is df.cumsum >= 100, the first 4 rows would be one group?

Comment: yes indeed. and then the next rows with cumsum >=  x and so on

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). First, create a new column to be used to group by. We can simply divide the `cumsum` column with the wanted granularity:

```
threshold = 5000
df['group'] = np.floor(df['cumsum'] / threshold)
```

`np.floor` is used here to make sure that the `>=` equality is kept, otherwise, just converting to int would work as well.

Now we can compute the aggregate values of each group. This can be done as follows:

```
df.groupby('group').agg({'price': 'ohlc'})
```

Comment: `np.ceil()` results in `cumsum <= threshold` instead of the desired `cumsum >= threshold`. else it looks good

Comment: for the `groupby` I can then use this:
`df.groupby('group').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})`

Comment: @steff: Ah, ye, you are correct. It should probably be `np.floor` instead (each group will then be `x*5000 >= v < (x+1)*5000)`. I adjusted the answer to account for this.

Comment: that doesn't change it unfortunately. it still results in `cumsum <= threshold`

Comment: @steff: Can you clarify a bit how you want the groups to be? If you only want `df.cumsum >= 5000` then everything after 5000 should be put into a single group? In my understanding it is 0-4999, 5000-9999, 10000, 14999, and so on. Is this correct (the above code should give this currently)?

Comment: I added my iterrows() solution to the question. Hope this clarifies. I need chunks which contain >= 5000 volume each. There shouldn't be a look ahead bias. As in I can only know that 5000 volume has been completed when the accumulated volume is 5000 or more.

Comment: @steff: If you need to reset the val to 0 after reaching 5000 and not using the remainder (the part above 5000) in the next group. Then I'm not sure if there is a better solution than iterating over the dataframe.

Comment: thanks for all your help. Going to code the `for loop` in plain ol python and then use `Numba` to speed it up.